# Почему блокируется выполнение потока

Tags: java, многопоточность

Здравствуйте,

Пишу многопоточное приложение на Java для конвертации видео и загрузки на ютьюб. Столкнулся со странной особенностью - она даже в плюс, то есть никак мне не мешает, но я понимаю, что это следствие ошибки и кривого проектирования, и хочу понять, где сделал глупость.

В приложении есть несколько потоков:

- поток, запускающий процесс кодировщика FFMpeg, забирающий данные из его вывода (консольного буфера) - класс наследуется от Thread;
- поток, запускающий этот поток, и привязывающийся к нему через waitFor() - ServiceRunner, класс наследуется от Thread;
- главный поток - в цикле по некоторому таймеру проверяет, не выставлен ли флаг остановки (если выставлен - прибивает системный процесс ffmpeg, поскольку иного способа его завершить нету, и проводит финализацию, вызывая нужную логику других классов;
- поток, обрабатывающий SwingUI, отрисовка интерфейса;
- в режиме "только загрузка без конвертации" есть ещё один поток, обновляющий Elapsed time и Remaining time счётчики раз в секунду по таймеру;
- поток Browser (extends Thread) - загрузка данных на ютьюб и обращения к API, использует Apache HttpClient

Всё работает довольно предсказуемо (кроме мелких нюансов вроде того, что в момент остановки из-за кривого кода могут быть не согласованы состояния в разных классах), кроме одного странного момента.

А именно, при запуске происходит блокирование всех потоков (ServiceRunner и Main) до того момента, как запущенный поток HttpConnect (static inner класс внутри Browser) получит данные. Этот HttpConnect - типа встроенного простейшего веб-сервера. Его задача - принять от ютьюба токен доступа, переданный по ссылке в редиректе. И вывести ссылку на панель управления видеороликами, чтобы юзер смог использовать открытую вкладку с пользой.

И вот здесь странно: стартует новый поток, в конструктор класса передаётся сокет, возвращаемый через accept(), аналогичный код работал в массе других проектов. Но здесь он работает не так. А именно, пока этот сокет не получит данные, кодирование не стартует. StreamGobbler, получающий данные от ffmpeg, и в этом режиме ещё и запускающий Browser (поскольку из Main этого сделать никак не получалось, весь код после старта этого потока не исполнялся) - не выполняется. Как показал отладочный вывод, цикл с таймерами в Main не выполняется тоже. Не выполняется ничего, кроме потока, где исполняется код класса Browser. UI, правда, работает.

И из-за этого мы не можем начать кодирование, пока пользователь не даст приложению доступ на ютьюб. В комбинированном режиме это может даже и логично, но ведь мы теряем драгоценное время. А могли бы выполнять полезную работу.

Как мне переписать код, чтобы проблемы не было?

Comment: как я понял, получение токена тоже в другом потоке выполняется, но все равно все висит ?

Comment: Получение токена выполняется в том же потоке, в котором потом идёт загрузка файла и вся работа с сетью. Там есть ещё логика, проверяющая, сколько процентов файла сконвертировано, и сколько байт вообще уже доступно на диске на данный момент (это старый вариант условия, я не стал его убирать на всякий случай). Если разница меньше чем в N процентов - следующий сегмент не грузим, вместо этого засыпаем на 10 секунд. Этот же поток получает токен в самом начале.

Comment: я так и не понял в каком потоке идет.  все таки в главном потоке выполняется получение токена или же где-то в другом (и не важно что делается в этом другом потоке)

Comment: Нет, не в главном. Но главный тормозится

Comment: а можно код получить ?

Comment: Да, конечно. http://popov654.pp.ru/copybox/YouTubeUploader.zip.

Смотрите ещё, чего я не до конца понял: при запуске ServiceRunner главный поток тоже приостанавливается (не проверял, на сколько, потом работа возобновляется, но следующая за этим инструкция, запускающая поток Browser-а, не выполнялась, как и печать в консоль, поставленная туда же). А при запуске Browser из ServiceRunner - приостанавливается уже ServiceRunner и тот, кто запущен от него. Правда ServiceRunner в консоль ничего не пишет, мне трудно сказать, что с ним в этот момент происходит.

Comment: ServiceRunner вообще можно было не наследовать от Thread. На том этапе я ещё не знал, что жизненно важно забирать вывод из буфера у процесса кодировщика, чтобы он не повисал, а когда сделал правильно, не понял, что эта прослойка уже не особо нужна. По факту ServiceRunner прикрепляется к StreamGobbler через waitFor(), и завершается в тот момент, когда завершается процесс ffmpeg через поток класса Main.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50020/discussion-between-senior-automator-and-alex654).

Answer (score 1):

Причина блокировки при старте в том, что обращение за токеном идет не в отдельном потоке, а в этом же.
В классе Browser в методе launch:

```
    instance = new Browser();
    Main.browser = instance;
    instance.run();
```

Вызов run не создает поток, для этого есть метод start.

PS: очень плохая практика наследоваться от класса Thread, для этого есть интерфейс Runnable.